# Biblatex Formating Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, formatting

Following the comments I'll start from the beginning.

I want to cite with superscore numbers and a list of references in the  bibliography in the following format:

**Book:**

> Surname, Name: Title. Subtitle, Location Year

**Journal:**

> Surname, Name: Title. Subtitle. In:
>   Journal, Release Date, Page

Multiple authors should be divided by a backslash!

So the bibliography should look like this.

> Jobs, Steve/Gates, Bill: Steve Jobs. In Memory. In: Weekly Apple, 1999, S.44-45

Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style = numeric,backend=biber,autocite = superscript]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

%\usepackage[style = geschichtsfrkl,citeinit = true, mitvn = true, jahrkeineklammern = true, mits = true, ibidpages = true, sorting=nyt, sortcase = true, autopunct=true, url = true, date = long, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}


\bibliography{Quellen} 

\renewcommand*{\autorenschriftart}{}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{. In:}

\begin{document}
This is a super nice example \autocite{BlaBla:1999}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And this is the bibliography file:

```
@Article{BlaBla:1999,
  author = {Jobs, Steve and Gates, Bill},
  title = {Steve Jobs},
  subtitle = {In Memory},
  journal = {Weekly Apple},
  location = {Silicon Valley},
  year = {1999},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {44--45},
  month = {january}
}
```

Thank you very much in advance! Any help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: How do you you want to cite inside the text? I think the style isn't a good choise because it's completed designed for footnote citations.

Comment: Thank you Daniel! I will have a look at it! I don't want citations inside the text, just a superscript number referencing the source inside the bibliography.And with the style... I thought this myself too, but it fulfills almost all my requirements und I desperately struggled to come to the same result with biblatex since I'm an absolute noob! ;)

Comment: I think you should start with `\usepackage[style = numeric,backend=biber,autocite = superscript]{biblatex}` and inside the text use `This is a super nice example\autocite{BlaBla:1999}`. After this we can modify your bibliography output.

Comment: I will give it a try, although I fear that much is to be done ;)

Comment: The `geschichtsfrkl` style has not been updated since 2012, and `biblatex` has changed quite a bit since then. Seeing that you are not too fussed about in text citations (the hard part to implement), you might want to modify `numeric` (as Marco Daniel suggested). Just explain what you would like to achieve (i.e. give the general format and maybe one or two real life examples and their expected output).

Comment: Is there any special formatting to be applied to any of the title fields - or fields in general (italic/emphasis/bold/quotation marks ... you name it). Is there a space after the slash? Or should it be "Jobs, Steve/Gates, Bill" or even "Jobs, Steve / Gates, Bill"?

Comment: Also: Are you sure you want all the volume/number information dropped from journal articles?

Comment: There should no be any special formatting in any of the fields and, this was my fault, there should not be a space after the slash, that means: Jobs, Steve/Gates, Bill! And thank you for formatting my post: it looks better now! Yes, I want it to be dropped; at least that is what my template tells me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code implements some of your wishes for the bibliography.

Formatting for a lot of fields is dropped via

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
```

The name format "First, Last/Second, Author" is enforced via

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
```

To get rid of months/volumes and number information

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{month}%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{volume}
     \clearfield{number}}
    {}
}
```

You can get rid of further fields by adding them to the list, for example

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{month}%
  \clearfield{series}
  \clearlist{publisher}
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{volume}
     \clearfield{number}}
    {}
}
```

Be aware though that there are different types of "fields", there are `field`, `list`, and `name`, and one needs to use the appropriate `\clear[...]` macro.

The name is separated from the title by a colon and the final period is dropped

```
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
```

This is for date formatting (publisher is dropped, plus comma before location)

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{location+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
      \printfield{series}%
      \setunit*{\addspace}%
      \printfield{number}}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style = numeric,backend=biber,autocite = superscript]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{BlaBla:1999,
  author = {Jobs, Steve and Gates, Bill},
  title = {Steve Jobs},
  subtitle = {In Memory},
  journal = {Weekly Apple},
  location = {Silicon Valley},
  year = {1999},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {44--45},
  month = {january},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{month}%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{volume}
     \clearfield{number}}
    {}
}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{location+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
      \printfield{series}%
      \setunit*{\addspace}%
      \printfield{number}}}}

\begin{document}
Some text\autocite{BlaBla:1999,cicero,wilde,coleridge}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output of the MWE above]

Comment: Thank you very much, you don't know how thankful I am! The last two things left for now are that there is a dot instead of a comma before the location in the book-entry and that there are still these nasty points at the end of the entries! In any case I will vote your answer up when I gained enough reputation!

Comment: @user45762 Have a look at the edited answer? Does this solve your two problems?

Comment: @user45762 I posted a wrong MWE earlier, sorry, that should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Here an expanded starting point:

1. Load `biblatex` with the style `numeric` and don't sort any entries. So they are appear in the bibliography in the same order as they cited:

   ```
   \usepackage[style = numeric,backend=biber,autocite = superscript,sorting=none]{biblatex}
   ```
2. Change the delimiters between authors:

   ```
   \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addslash\space}
   ```

Here an example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Quellen.bib}
@Article{BlaBla:1999,
author = {Jobs, Steve},
title = {Steve Jobs},
subtitle = {In Memory},
journal = {Weekly Apple},
location = {Silicon Valley},
year = {1999},
volume = {1},
pages = {44--45},
month = {january}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style = numeric,backend=biber,autocite = superscript,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

%\bibliography{Quellen}
\addbibresource{Quellen.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addslash\space}

\begin{document}
This is a super nice example\autocite{BlaBla:1999}

This is a super nice example\autocite{companion}

This is a super nice example\autocite{knuth:ct:a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]