# Define how printed bibliography looks based on source

Tags: biblatex

After a while I have to write a paper again and I want to use my old LaTeX template which is still working without problems. One thing I noticed and which bothers me is that the bibliography looks different for `Books`, `Journals`, etc.
As this is probably intended I would prefer a more consistent look.

For example:

```
@article{Carpenter.2011,
 author = {Carpenter, Jason M. and Brosdahl, Deborah J.C.},
 year = {2011},
 title = {Exploring retail format choice among US males},
 urldate = {2015-05-28},
 pages = {886--898},
 volume = {39},
 number = {12},
 journal = {International Journal of Retail {\&} Distribution Management},
 doi = {10.1108/09590551111183290}
}
```

would print the title with encapsulated "" and the name of the journal in italic. Whereas a book would have its title in italic.

```
@book{Alpar.2014,
 author = {Alpar, Paul and Alt, Rainer and Bensberg, Frank and Grob, Heinz Lothar and Weimann, Peter and Winter, Robert},
 year = {2014},
 title = {Anwendungsorientierte Wirtschaftsinformatik: Strategische Planung, Entwicklung und Nutzung von Informationssystemen},
 keywords = {Computer Science;Information Systems;Management information systems},
 address = {Wiesbaden},
 edition = {7., aktualisierte u. erw. Aufl. 2014},
 publisher = {{Springer Vieweg}},
 isbn = {3658005211},
 series = {SpringerLink : B{\"u}cher}
}
```

And this basically happens for other types too and I haven't even seen other types yet.

In addition I am using biblatex package.

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, isbn=false, doi=false, maxcitenames=2, uniquename=true, maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
```

My questions are, how do I change this where is the config file for this?

And if that is not a good idea..can I split my bibliography automatically into categories so that my lecturer can see that it is consistent for the same type of cited source?

Or should I use another approach?

Comment: Please see [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864). Currently your questions is quite unspecific and seems to me to be more or less a duplicate of the question there. So if you can make your question more specific, please do so.

Comment: On a different note: What you seem to see as inconsistencies has some logic in it and seems to be accepted widely throughout many scientific communities, so it might not be too bad after all.

Comment: Like @moewe I think there's some logic to these "apparent" inconsistencies in formatting styles between two bibliographic `@type`s. A journal article has, an article title & a journal title; whereas, a book will have only its own (book) title. Therefore, journal title = (book) title = `<italic>` & article title = null = `<"...">`. Don't you think it's logical?

Comment: Also, I would strongly advice to ask your lecturer's opinion regarding the standard/ non-standard formatting of citations, before applying such formatting style changes (if any). If your lecturer doesn't want them, all your time & efforts could go to waste and that would be so disappointing!

Comment: To drive Amar's point home: The book title and journal title are very much equivalent in the sense that if you are in a library they are the first thing you see on the volume you take from the shelf (plus, they are the thing you look for to find the work in the first place: There is no point in roaming the shelves not knowing which book or journal to look for.). The article title then is more or less just a chapter title in a book, something you see after you have opened the volume. So it is only natural to have both formatted in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to whether there are any biblatex styles that would fit your need, or how you would go about creating your own, but if you decide to go the route of having separate bibliographies for articles and books, just specify which type you want when you print the bibliography; for example `\printbibliography[type=book]` will print a list of books only.  Similarly `\printbibliography[type=article]` will print articles only.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you do decide to go ahead with the "consistent" look, the default formatting for several fields can be dropped using the following lines of code in your preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
```

In your case, you may only need to add the corresponding lines for `journaltitle`, `booktitle`, & `title`.

Taken from: [First code snippet provided in this answer by @moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159455/78565)